# decode hevc on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, hevc

I'm trying to make a video player on android using android-ffmpeg, it works fine with avc streams, but failed to decode hevc ones. Are there any special requirements for decoding hevc on android with android-ffmpeg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HEVC decoder based on OpenHEVC was introduced in FFmpeg version 2.1 according to https://www.ffmpeg.org/ (scroll down to the October 28, 2013 entry)